# ¿Cómo obtener reacciones de una foto de Facebook con Graph API?

Tags: php, facebook, opengraph

Necesito obtener el número de "me gusta", "me encanta" y demás reacciones de una foto de facebook, utilizando graph api de facebook o algún otro método.

Answer (score 0):

Dado que conoces el identificador único de la foto (por ejemplo, [10092511675_10154419267331676](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895?method=GET&path=10092511675_10154419267331676%3Ffields%3Dreactions%2Cactions&version=v2.6))

Entonces el llamado consiste en ese ID incluyendo la entidad `reactions`

```
v2.6/10092511675_10154419267331676?fields=reactions
```

Esto lo puedes ver experimentando con [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895?method=GET&path=10092511675_10154419267331676%3Ffields%3Dreactions%2Cactions&version=v2.6).

Este llamado es equivalente a pedir:

```
v2.6/10092511675_10154419267331676/reactions
```

Al cliente de la librería con que te conectes habrá que añadirle la lógica para iterar sobre la respuesta y requerir la url de la siguiente página, repitiendo esta acción hasta dar con una respuesta sin reacciones. Para casos simples, se puede evitar esta paginación modificando el límite de reacciones que se desea obtener en cada petición:

```
v2.6/10092511675_10154419267331676/reactions?limit=900
```

Pero dependiendo de los detalles de tu implementación, puede que asumir un máximo de 900 likes sea insuficiente y no evitarás la lógica del paginado. En el fondo, los detalles de implementación que cada uno debe resolver a su manera son

- La librería para conectarse al API
- La App de facebook con que te identificarás ante Facebook a la hora de requerir al API.
- La lógica para iterar sobre el paginado.